# Long and short range correlations in nuclear physics

Tags: nuclear-physics, interactions, mean-field-theory

In the introduction of chapter 6 of Ring and Schuck's book "The nuclear many-body problem" it is stated that "the Hartree-Fock method partially takes into account the particle-hole part of the interaction, that is, the long-range part of the force" and also "the short range part of the force which causes particle-particle correlations". I do not understand why the long range part of the force causes 1p1h excitations while the short range takes care of particle-particle correlations (which I assume means pairing?).